# Flurry Analytics, Flurry AppCircle, Flurry Clips in Flurry iPhone SDK

Tags: flurry

Can any one please send me Flurry SDK which Consists of AppCircle and Clips.

On [dev.flurry.com](http://dev.flurry.com),  I downloaded the flurry SDK 3.0.9.

From these I don't get the ***FlurryClips.h*** file and library file also. Then how to play the clips? Can any one please help me.

If there any SDK's, please forward me.

Thanks,
nikkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently faced the same problem, and I wrote to flurry support: support@flurry.com, and next day they send me ubiquitous SDK (version 4) with clips, analytics and all the stuff.

I don't know why they don't just share this SDK for public access, though...